# Scaling a whole page to a veiwport while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, web

I have a page with a small game on, the UI of which I have designed to work with a viewport with a resolution of 1280x800 (or thereabouts). I'd like to maintain this look on differently sized screens, allowing the page to occupy 100% of the viewport width and have the height adjust accordingly. In effect resizing the entire page as you would when using in an image editor.

Initially I approached this by surrounding all of the elements within the `<body>` tag with `<div id = "wrapper">` and setting `width:100%;` but, this page has a number of elements set to `position:absolute;` meaning that while the rest of the page was resized accordingly, those elements remained in place. This also had the effect of not altering the size of some elements whose sizes were set in `px` as opposed to `%` or `ems`.

```
<body>
    <div id = 'wrapper'>
        <content></content>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
```

My next approach was to embed the page in another page entirely with an `<iframe>` element and wrap *that* in a `div` but the contents of the `<iframe>` simply spilled spilled over, and you would have had to scroll to see the page.

```
<body>
    <div id = 'wrapper'>
        <iframe src = 'game.html' width = '1280' height = '800'></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
```

How can I achieve this? Ideally using just CSS and HTML but I don't mind all that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've understood the question correctly, you could create a ratio box using a percentage `padding-top`. It is a useful pattern for a few different scenarios.

It works due to the fact that `padding-top` percentage values take their percentage from the element width rather than height.

Here is a simple example:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top:62.5%; /* 800/1280 */
}

.game {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  background: black;
}

.gameui_example {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="game">
      <!-- game markup goes here -->
      <div class="gameui_example"></div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Note that it doesn't handle anything like if the viewport height is shorter than the 1280x800 ratio. Depending on how much you want it to adapt you might need to use a media query or two.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I think those elements which are in absolute position will just have a to be adjusted since it seems they just can't be repositioned as relative within another div, cheers!

Comment: @CallumMcshane glad it works for you! If the absolute elements are children of the `.game` div they should be positioned relative to it. I have added a small example to my snippet.